# Displaying an offset cell based off an address from a cell address lookup formula

Tags: offset

I’m trying to create a Quiz answer sheet that will display the questions that were incorrectly answered, as well as the correct answer afterwards upon completion for study purposes.

Rather than link individual cells, I’m trying to utilize a formula based on the answer key, where the letters are assigned a numerical value to correlate to a row offset for the question, so I won’t have to rebuild this, only change the answers, and it will auto create.

To better explain:

Column A = Question number (numerical 1-100) (auto fills as answers are put in cells)

Column B = locked/hidden answer key (A-D)

Column C = Result display (Incorrect/Correct)

Column D = Incorrect Question Display based on INDEX lookup  (=IF(F3=FALSE,E3&L3," ") ) [FALSE is if there is an entry in the answer cell and it is incorrect]

Column E = Lookup for Question Display ( =INDEX(Test!$B$3:$D$490,MATCH(Results!$A3,Test!$B$3:$B$490,0),2) )

Column L = written answer from quiz – cannot figure out how to link this cell utilizing the information available to me

I can get the address for the questions (cannot figure out how to utilize them in a formula to get the rows either).

Or I can get the above.

Or, I can go the old route and Ctrl+pgup and Ctrl+pgdn and link the cells directly, and not have it be automated. (I’d rather not go that route, lol)

Thank you for any advice!

Any advice out there?

VLOOKUP
HLOOKUP
INDEX
CELL("ADDRESS",INDEX(
INDEX/MATCH

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add tags for what language you are using; perhaps you're discussing [excel]? [offset] tells us nothing about what you're doing; see [What are tags, and how should I use them?](/help/tagging).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Put offset inside the index.

```
=INDEX((OFFSETTest!$B$3:$B$490,<ANSWER REFERENCE NUMBER A=1,B=2...>,1)),MATCH(Results!$A3,Test!$B$3:$B$490,0))
```